# AMP Experiment fails to switch on

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

Anyone experienced an issue where amp x takes a while to switch on? Running this  on chrome dev tools returns false:

```
AMP.isExperimentOn()
```

At times, I've found that running on an incognito tab works but not always

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think there's some confusion due to a naming collision. `AMP.isExperimentOn()` is for internal features listed [here](https://cdn.ampproject.org/experiments.html) and is unrelated to the `amp-experiment` extension.

Comment: Thanks for getting back William. Are you able to comment on why "amp-x-experiment-name='the-variant'" is *not always* set in the body tag i.e. amp x does not always "switch on"